# How does acetone help to make a liquid cleaner stronger?

Tags: solubility, solutions, solvents

Acetone, as a solvent, seems to behave somewhat different than other solvents. It seems to solve things other unpolar solvents do not.

For example, I have two cleaner sprays from the same brand, and the one with acetone seems to be "stronger" in some way. I think I have noticed that difference before elsewhere, so I assume at least part of what makes it stronger is the acetone.

Comment: Acetone is pretty polar on the scale of solvents. See eg https://people.chem.umass.edu/xray/solvent.html

Comment: It's not special at all.

Comment: At the same time, I don't see why this deserves downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

Well, acetone is at the same time polar (so it likes water) and lipophilic (so it likes fat). As such, it is a very good solvent.

Comment: I would add that relative toxicity, price, and the right volatility (easy drying and removal as well relatively easy distillation) also contribute to make acetone so special. Plus one for the simple answer.

Comment: I changed the title significantly, but for your answer should be no change.